# How to create thread every X seconds but only if previous iteration thread is finished in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a following requirement:
"Create a detached worker thread at every X seconds but only if previously created detached thread is finished. If at the end of timeout, previous thread is not finished, then terminate it and create new thread."

Note that, I have a requirement of creating detached thread, because I don't want my main thread to wait for it to finish.

I am using C++11 thread class.

Any help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create the new thread at the end of the previous thread?

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu yes. I have a fixed thread creation timeout (300s). At the end of timeout, I want to check whether the last created thread (detached) still alive or not. If not alive, then only create new thread. Objective is to have only single worker thread at a time.

Comment: Do you really need to create multiple threads? Why not reuse the single thread to just run the worker function in an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, I have to create a new thread for each timeout. Because thread creation also depends on other params. If there is no data to fetch, no need to continue thread running.

Comment: Are you a GUI or a console/service app?  If you are a GUI, this is easy.  Console or service app - slightly different story.

Comment: It's a Linux terminal CLI..

Comment: Re, "...no need to continue thread running." OK, but what _harm_ is there in having the thread sleep until the next time it is needed? Continually creating and destroying short-lived threads can be more of burden on system resources than allowing one long-lived thread to sleep when it isn't needed. That's the whole reason why _[thread pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_ were invented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on the comment by Sedat Kapanoglu, you could start the new thread at the end of the current, but add a timeout if the "every X second" haven't passed yet.

You could do this with a wrapper function.

Perhaps something similar to this:

```
void worker_wrapper()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // Run actual worker function
    worker();

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // If less than 300 seconds have passed, wait for the remainder of the 300 seconds
    if (end - start < 300s)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(300s - (end - start));
    }

    // Create a new thread
    std::thread next_thread(worker_wrapper);
    next_thread.detach();
}
```

You could of course add conditions to check if the new thread should be started or not.